# How do I make an alias to substitute single word in a piped command?

Tags: command-line, pipe, alias, arguments

I use aliases a lot but right now only for use cases like `alias i='sudo apt-get install -y'`. I often would like to add an alias in the following form:

`alias cmd='echo [something] >> /path/to/file'` where I would like to substitute [something] with what I enter after the `cmd`.

I can obviously create a one-line script,save it somewhere and make an alias to that command but since I only want to substitute **only 1 word in a pipe**, is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are perfectly suitable for this purpose. For example:

```
cmd() { echo $* >> /path/to/file'; }
```

This is on one line, just like an alias. But it can take parameters.

Comment: Does the `$*` mean to take *all* of the command line arguments supplied?

Comment: Yes. You can use `$1` if you want only the first argument.